# Перемещение данных между двумя QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Есть массив данных `QByteArray data`.Нужно взять из его начала кусок и переместить в другой `QByteArray`. Делаю так:

```
QByteArray pack(data.data(),pack_size);
data.remove(0,pack_size);
```

Все работает нормально, но хотелось бы избежать излишних копирований и удалений.

Comment: возможно, то что Вы ищите - [fromRawData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData)

Answer (score 6):

Нет, так сделать нельзя. `QByteArray` управляет определённым непрерывным куском в памяти, поэтому нельзя просто переместить его часть. Только копирование. Я бы код написал так:

```
QByteArray pack = data.left(pack_size);
data = data.mid(pack_size);
```